# I Want To Group By similar number and get count

Tags: sql

Select * from TableName

```
Field1
2019063207
2019063207_1
2019063207_2
2019063207_3
2019063208
2019063208_1
2019063208_2
2019063209
2019063210
```

I expect

```
Number     Count 
2019063207   4
2019063208   3 
2019063209   1  
2019063210   1
```

- i am Using This select ClientCode,PARSENAME(REPLACE(UniqueCode,'_','.'),2)  from [Table Name] But Not Working

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please share in table format.

Comment: microsoft Sql server management studio 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like that ([result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d24feb33a90d2b2a941c8dd13e2db60)):

```
select substring(field1,1,case when charindex('_',field1) = 0 then len(field1) else charindex('_',field1)-1 end ) as code, count(*) 
from t1
group by substring(field1,1,case when charindex('_',field1) = 0 then len(field1) else charindex('_',field1)-1 end )
```

Or by using CTE ([result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ad1dfd6a29b9fedb1ea973a4fbd68ea))

```
with codes as (select substring(field1,1,case when charindex('_',field1) = 0 then len(field1) else charindex('_',field1)-1 end ) as code 
from t1)
select code, count(*) 
from codes
group by code
```